# Ad-Blocker in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, adblock

From `iOS 9`Apple start ad-blocker in safari by installing the blocker and use it as [described](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/iosapps/how-use-ad-blockers-in-ios-9-but-why-you-shouldnt-3627089/) here.

**My question is how to use ad-blocker for `UIWebView`??**

I mean if my app has `UIWebView` and I wanted to block `ad-mob` in my `UIWebView`. If it is possible then how achieve this, if not then is there any alternative solution is available.

**Already done R&D**

I already go through many site and apple doc's I didn't get any source which explains my question.

In apple doc I got [NEFilterProvider](https://developer.apple.com/reference/networkextension/nefilterprovider).

According to apple, `NEFilterProvider` examines network content as it passes through the network stack on the device and decides if the network content should be blocked or allowed to pass on to its final destination.

But i don't know how to use `NEFilterProvider`.

If you have any further knowledge please share.

Thanks.